# How to Identify/Select features from WMS?

Tags: qgis-3, wms, features, identify

I'm trying to extract some features from the following WMS:

http://servicios.idee.es/wms-inspire/hidrografia

Namely, one layer called "Red hidrografica", which contains the traces of rivers and streams for all of Spain.

I've realized that by using the "Identify feature" option I'm able to select one particular river, copy the feature and paste it to a vector layer (even though the original is ostensible a WMS/raster layer).

[image: Feature selected]

This works, but it can be frustrating as the feature identification only seems to work when I click exactly on the river.

Any slight deviation results in nothing being identified, so I've had to spend a few minutes clicking at random around each feature trying to select them.

If I try to select a wider area, it fails to identify the only feature in the layer that falls within this area.

[image: Trying to select by area does not work]

Is there a way to have this "Select by area" do what I need it to do?

Or some way to increase the size of the "Click-Identification-box-area"?

Comment: No,  WMS GetFeatureInfo only works on an x,y/i,j (depending on WMS version) pixel coordinate from the viewed image.  The result may include the geometry of the whole selected feature or features, or just some feature information at that point based on some buffer etc, which is a decision of the service provider rather than a client decision.  You may get different results depending on info_format requested.

Comment: However there is an associated WFS ~ http://servicios.idee.es/wfs-inspire/hidrografia?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities  so you might find that more useful

Comment: @nmtoken - Thanks. I had tried using that WFS before, but whenever I try loading it in QGIS I get an error (" Layer is not valid"). That is why I had resorted to the WMS. I'm not sure if it's because I'm failing to use the WFS propperly or because htere is some issue with the WFS itself. Can you confirm if you are able to access it?

Comment: The WFS is accessible, example GetFeature request is https://servicios.idee.es/wfs-inspire/hidrografia?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=hy-p:Watercourse&count=1  the issue is that QGIS can't handle this complex feature type natively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WMS are not best suited to allow a multiple selection on the features it contains. You are essentially selecting an individual pixel in the image hence why you can't really use the polygon to select.

A long and pointless work around would be to use some imaging software to extract the features but this is fairly limited.

I think your best bet is to find a vector format of the rivers and waterways which I am sure will be publicly available to some extent. A quick Google found this:

[Link 1](https://mapcruzin.com/free-spain-arcgis-maps-shapefiles.htm)

[Link 2 Diva GIS](https://www.diva-gis.org/gdata)

Comment: Not sure it's correct to say that `WMS are not really designed to select any let alone multiple feature` as the WMS GetFeatureInfo request is designed for that very purpose, to get the value of the feature (or features) in the underlying data set (or data sets), granted you need to click on a pixel coordinate in the 'image'.

Comment: Thanks that is a very fair point. I will amend. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to do this using the WMS, as my previous attempts at using the WFS had failed.

I've contacted the WFS provider, and their reply is:

"This is a known issue with QGIS. (...) If you try loading a WFS 2.0.0 in QGIS, the layers will show in the list as the program is able to read the Capabilities, but is unable to download the features, as it is unable to interpret their GML."

They say trying with version 1.0.0 or 1.1.0, or using an older version of QGIS (2.18) with the plugin "WFS 2.0 Client" might allow some access, but even so they claim some features will remain inaccesible.

Comment: It's a know issue with many clients not just QGIS.  clients can't handle complex features or can't handle them very well.  service providers though must produce these feature types to conform to INSPIRE data models.  It's not WFS 2 that's the issue here, its the feature types.